How can I create intervals with Python in order to get most similar size of each group (interval) based on specific criteria?
Please can you propose a solution for the following task?
Lets say I have a dataframe like this:
data = {
    "Town": ["F", "A", "N", "O", "B", "L", "C", "K", "J", "E", "G", "M", "I", "D", "H"],
    "Hungarian_rate": [1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 15, 15, 20, 22, 23, 31, 41, 60, 75],
    "Population": [40, 10, 30, 50, 30, 20, 40, 30, 20, 20, 20, 10, 40, 50, 30]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I'm working on creating 5 intervals based on the column Hungarian rate. The goal is to create intervals where the total sum of population is as similar as possible between them. The code added below creates intervals only based on the similarity of the count of towns in each interval.
df["interval"] = pd.qcut(df.Hun_rate, q=5)

grouped = df.groupby("interval").size().reset_index(name='num')

grouped

BUT I'm aiming to generate 5 intervals based on the 'Hungarians rate (%)' column, with the intention of achieving similar total sums of population within each interval.
Below, you can see the desired outcome.

I've tried to find a solution for creating intervals through various sources like Stack Overflow and AI, but haven't been successful. Could you please provide guidance on how to create intervals based on specific criteria?

This sounds more like an optimization problem to me

It is as is mentioned in the comments, an optimization problem in which you aim to optimize the number of individuals in each interval, basically trying to reach target_population_per_interval = total_population / num_intervals. Here is a suggestion to how you could do this:
import pandas as pd

# Data setup
data = {
    "Town": ["F", "A", "N", "O", "B", "L", "C", "K", "J", "E", "G", "M", "I", "D", "H"],
    "Hungarian_rate": [1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 15, 15, 20, 22, 23, 31, 41, 60, 75],
    "Population": [40, 10, 30, 50, 30, 20, 40, 30, 20, 20, 20, 10, 40, 50, 30]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_sorted = df.sort_values(by="Hungarian_rate")

num_intervals = 5

total_population = df_sorted['Population'].sum()
target_population_per_interval = total_population / num_intervals

current_population = 0
interval_number = 0
interval_start = df_sorted.iloc[0]['Hungarian_rate']
intervals = []
interval_bounds = []

for index, row in df_sorted.iterrows():
    if interval_number < num_intervals - 1:
        if abs((current_population + row['Population']) - target_population_per_interval) < abs(current_population - target_population_per_interval):
            current_population += row['Population']
            intervals.append(interval_number)
        else:
            interval_end = df_sorted.at[index - 1, 'Hungarian_rate'] if index > 0 else row['Hungarian_rate']
            interval_bounds.append((interval_start, interval_end))
            interval_start = row['Hungarian_rate']
            interval_number += 1
            current_population = row['Population']
            intervals.append(interval_number)
    else:
        intervals.append(interval_number)

interval_end = df_sorted.iloc[-1]['Hungarian_rate']
interval_bounds.append((interval_start, interval_end))

df_sorted['Interval'] = intervals

interval_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Interval_Number': range(num_intervals),
    'Range': interval_bounds,
    'Count': df_sorted.groupby('Interval').size().values,
    'Population_Sum': df_sorted.groupby('Interval')['Population'].sum().values
})

print(interval_df)


which will give you
   Interval_Number     Range  Count  Population_Sum
0                0    (1, 5)      3              80
1                1    (8, 9)      2              80
2                2  (10, 15)      3              90
3                3  (20, 31)      4              70
4                4  (41, 75)      3             120

However, I doubted that you will be able to achieve the expected output you posted in the image with a simple decision logic.
There are however other ways to do this, for instance greedy algorithm, but it all depends on the size of your actual dataset. These are heavy. Here is an example which allows you to tweak a parameterm threshold. What it does is that it tries to distribute the population in 5 intervals in such a way that the difference in population count between intervals is smaller that "threshold". A word of caution though: This is computationally costly:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "Town": ["F", "A", "N", "O", "B", "L", "C", "K", "J", "E", "G", "M", "I", "D", "H"],
    "Hungarian_rate": [1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 15, 15, 20, 22, 23, 31, 41, 60, 75],
    "Population": [40, 10, 30, 50, 30, 20, 40, 30, 20, 20, 20, 10, 40, 50, 30]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by="Hungarian_rate").reset_index(drop=True)

num_intervals = 5

interval_populations = np.zeros(num_intervals)
intervals = np.zeros(len(df_sorted), dtype=int)
threshold = 20

for i in range(len(df_sorted)):
    row = df_sorted.iloc[i]
    current_interval = intervals[i]
    new_population = interval_populations[current_interval] + row['Population']
    if current_interval < num_intervals - 1 and new_population > interval_populations[current_interval]:
        current_interval += 1
        intervals[i] = current_interval
    interval_populations[current_interval] += row['Population']

while True:
    max_idx = np.argmax(interval_populations)
    min_idx = np.argmin(interval_populations)
    max_pop = interval_populations[max_idx]
    min_pop = interval_populations[min_idx]

    if max_idx == min_idx or (max_pop - min_pop) < threshold:
        break

    for i in range(len(df_sorted)):
        if intervals[i] == max_idx:
            proposed_new_max = max_pop - df_sorted.at[i, 'Population']
            proposed_new_min = min_pop + df_sorted.at[i, 'Population']

            if abs(proposed_new_max - proposed_new_min) < abs(max_pop - min_pop):
                intervals[i] = min_idx
                interval_populations[max_idx] -= df_sorted.at[i, 'Population']
                interval_populations[min_idx] += df_sorted.at[i, 'Population']
                break

df_sorted['Interval'] = intervals

interval_summary = df_sorted.groupby('Interval').agg(
    Population_Sum=('Population', 'sum'),
    Towns=('Town', list),
    Count=('Town', 'size')
).reset_index()

print(interval_summary)

which gives you (for the threshold = 25):
   Interval  Population_Sum         Towns  Count
0         0             100     [F, C, E]      3
1         1              80        [D, H]      2
2         2              90  [A, B, K, G]      4
3         3              80  [N, L, J, M]      4
4         4              90        [O, I]      2


Thank you for your answer Serge. The first code what you provided works well on that example. But unfortunately when I tried to apply it on my whole dataset there are some issues. My real dataset looks like more like this:
data = {"ID": list(range(1, 34)),
"Hungarian_rate": [
    0.042301184, 0.081788441, 0.1, 0.124843945, 0.125313283, 0.138888889, 0.227401933, 0.323924109, 
    0.343249428, 0.451807229, 0.469483568, 0.477326969, 0.539665407, 0.557813372, 0.609756098, 
    0.810144417, 0.828729282, 0.831600832, 1.715854496, 2.027843112, 2.173913043, 3.90625, 
    8.671534038, 26.1589404, 28.10188989, 41.54411765, 44.70899471, 46.6640032, 61.59060099, 
    72.39892985, 73.69888476, 77.63819095, 79.12844037
],
"Population": [
    0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 9, 6, 5, 0, 46, 0, 4, 7, 50, 5, 10, 6, 0, 16, 130, 2, 2, 295, 
    7, 29, 17, 21, 83, 44, 160, 18, 24, 3
]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I applied your first code.
The error was: All arrays must be of the same length.
Some of the arrays had different length.
Length of Interval_Number: 5
Length of Range: 5
Length of Count: 4
Length of Population_Sum: 4
I fixed this problem, i changed the end of the code:
interval_df = pd.DataFrame({
'Interval_Number': range(num_intervals),
'Range': interval_bounds})
interval_counts = df_sorted.groupby('Interval').size().reindex(range(num_intervals), fill_value=0).values 
interval_population_sum = df_sorted.groupby('Interval')['Population'].sum().reindex(range(num_intervals), fill_value=0).values
interval_df['Count'] = interval_counts
interval_df['Population_Sum'] = interval_population_sum

So now I got a table. But with wrong intervals, where the sum of population are not similar:

Could you please give an advise why in this case, on this type of data its not working?
Thank you in forward.

I have in my dataset Null values. This caused the problem. I fixed it.
